# Trigger React Router state update

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a web app that uses React and React Router. Within the app I have an easy time navigating using the `History` object.

But I noticed that if in my console (or from my tests) I try to navigate using `window.history.pushState(..)` then nothing happens!

How do I make react-router respect the actual `history` object instead of their own wrapper?

I tried forwarding `pushState` calls from `window.history` to the internal `History` but it always ends up w/ infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do this properly. :(

I'm doing a workaround using this hack:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from 'history';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    reactHistory: History;
  }
}

window.reactHistory = createBrowserHistory({...});
```

And then from my tests I'm calling `reactHistory.replace(<path here>)`.